# Write Base64-encoded image to file

Tags: java, image, base64, decode, encode

How to write a Base64-encoded image to file?

I have encoded an image to a string using Base64.
First, I read the file, then convert it to a byte array and then apply Base64 encoding to convert the image to a string.

Now my problem is how to decode it.

```
byte dearr[] = Base64.decodeBase64(crntImage);
File outF = new File("c:/decode/abc.bmp");
BufferedImage img02 = ImageIO.write(img02, "bmp", outF);
```

The variable `crntImage` contains the string representation of the image.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Assuming the image data is already in the format you want, you don't need `ImageIO` at all - you just need to write the data to the file:

```
// Note preferred way of declaring an array variable
byte[] data = Base64.decodeBase64(crntImage);
try (OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream("c:/decode/abc.bmp")) {
    stream.write(data);
}
```

(I'm assuming you're using Java 7 here - if not, you'll need to write a manual try/finally statement to close the stream.)

If the image data *isn't* in the format you want, you'll need to give more details.

Comment: I used your above code. I am working on java web services where i am getting base64 string of uploaded image form IOS device. When i tried your above code in separate application i get original image as it is. But when i tried it with web services image is not created. When i debug application in both cases the byte array for same base64 string is different in length. Why i am getting this problem.

Comment: @Aniket: That doesn't give *nearly* enough information for us to help you. I suggest you ask a new question with more context - what the web service is, how it's implemented, how you're uploading the image data, what you've observed etc.

Comment: I posted question on below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27378069/convert-base64-string-to-image-not-working

Comment: "I'm assuming you're using Java 7" => you meant Java 8, not Java 7. Afaik both Base64 and try-with-resources are Java 8.

Comment: @Toto: No, try-with-resources was definitely in Java 7: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/try-with-resources.html Java 8 wasn't released when I wrote this answer, although I guess it was available in beta. But the `Base64` class that the OP is using isn't the one in the JDK, either. (It doesn't have a `decodeBase64` method.)

Comment: Helpful answer,but it didn't work first time. I needed to use the Base64 getDecoder() method, like so: byte[] data = Base64.getDecoder().decode(crntImage);

Comment: @DAB: I strongly suspect we're talking about different `Base64` classes then. I suspect the OP was using the Apache one: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html

Comment: @jonskeet Yes, you're right, I think. I have added another answer below.

Answer (score 38):

## With Java 8's [`Base64`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) API

```
byte[] decodedImg = Base64.getDecoder()
                    .decode(encodedImg.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
Path destinationFile = Paths.get("/path/to/imageDir", "myImage.jpg");
Files.write(destinationFile, decodedImg);
```

If your encoded image starts with something like `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0...`, you'll have to remove the part. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23979842/convert-base64-string-to-image#23979996) for an easy way to do that.

Answer (score 6):

No need to use BufferedImage, as you already have the image file in a byte array

```
    byte dearr[] = Base64.decodeBase64(crntImage);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("c:/decode/abc.bmp")); 
    fos.write(dearr); 
    fos.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.Base64;
```

.... Just making it clear that this answer uses the java.util.Base64 package, without using any third-party libraries.

```
String crntImage=<a valid base 64 string>

byte[] data = Base64.getDecoder().decode(crntImage);

try( OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream("d:/temp/abc.pdf") ) 
{
   stream.write(data);
}
catch (Exception e) 
{
   System.err.println("Couldn't write to file...");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Other option using apache-commons:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

...
File file = new File( "path" );
byte[] bytes = Base64.decodeBase64( "base64" );
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile( file, bytes );
```

Answer (score -7):

Try this:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class WriteImage 
{   
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        BufferedImage image = null;
        try {

            URL url = new URL("URL_IMAGE");
            image = ImageIO.read(url);

            ImageIO.write(image, "jpg",new File("C:\\out.jpg"));
            ImageIO.write(image, "gif",new File("C:\\out.gif"));
            ImageIO.write(image, "png",new File("C:\\out.png"));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP doesn't have a URL. They have the image data in base64 - something your answer completely ignores.