# Saving an Image from Base64 String Does not Open

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, base64, javax.imageio

On the client Side I am using Jquery to convert an Image from image to a Base64 String and sending it back to the server. On the server I am storing the String as it is and it is also rendering back on the required pages when i pit  the image shows nicely. however when I use this class below I am not able to store the image on the disk on the server or use ImageIO.read or using output Stream it does not show up after wards.

```
public static void saveCompanyLogo(String path,String logo,String comId){
    String s[]=logo.split(";");
    String format=s[0].substring(11);
    File file = new File(path+"SecurePass\\logos\\");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        boolean result = false;

        try{
            File f=new File(path+"SecurePass\\logos\\");
            f.mkdir();
            result = true;
        } catch(SecurityException se){
            //handle it
        }        
        if(result) {    
        }
    }
    byte[] b=Base64.decodeBase64(logo.replaceAll(" ", "+"));
    try (OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(path+"SecurePass\\logos\\"+comId+"."+format)) {
        stream.write(b);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

I am using replaceAll on the suggestion of a Overflow user, but no go. Please help. In the above code "logo" contains the Base64 String. I have also used ImageIO.read using imagereaders but no go. Seems that something is wrong in the data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it easily by using `canvas`. Like this:

```
var img =document.getElementbyId('image');

function baseImage(img){ // img is the image object
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                canvas.width = img.width;
                canvas.height = img.height;

                // Copy the image contents to the canvas
                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);

                // Get the data-URL formatted image
                var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");

                return dataURL.replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", "");
}
```

Comment: You do not read the post nicely.. I am saying I have problems on server.. Above code is server side code.. I simply want to save the base64 String as an image... on the server... Why mark me down... I have no problem relating the client side..!

Answer (score 0):

WE have to strip off the String from the client string .. details on this post..

[Convert base64 string to image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23979842/convert-base64-string-to-image)