# How to decode SafetyNet JWS response?

Tags: android, base64, jwt, jjwt

I am investigating SafetyNet provided by Google within my Android Application.

To start with I simply called the SafetyNet attest API and Base64 decoded the parts as shown in the Google supplied examples.

```
SafetyNet.getClient(this).attest(NONCE, <API KEY>)
        .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<SafetyNetApi.AttestationResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(final SafetyNetApi.AttestationResponse attestationResponse) {
                initialDataExtraction(attestationResponse.getJwsResult());
            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull final Exception exception) {
                if (exception instanceof ApiException) {
                    final ApiException apiException = (ApiException) exception;
                    Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: " + apiException.getMessage() + " " + apiException.getStatusCode());
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error: ", exception);
                }
            }
        });
```

I extract the JWS parts as follows:-

```
private byte[] initialDataExtraction(final String jwsResult) {

    final String[] jwsResultParts = jwsResult.split("[.]");
    if (jwsResultParts.length == 3) {
        final byte[] header = Base64.decode(jwsResultParts[0], Base64.NO_WRAP);
        final byte[] data = Base64.decode(jwsResultParts[1], Base64.NO_WRAP);
        final byte[] signature = Base64.decode(jwsResultParts[2], Base64.NO_WRAP);

        Log.d(TAG, "initialDataExtraction: header = " + new String(header, UTF_8));
        Log.d(TAG, "initialDataExtraction: data = " + new String(data, UTF_8));
        Log.d(TAG, "initialDataExtraction: signature = " + new String(signature, UTF_8));

        return data;
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "initialDataExtraction: Failure: Illegal JWS signature format. The JWS consists of " + jwsResultParts.length + " parts instead of 3.");
        return null;
    }
}
```

I am using `android.util.Base64` to decode the parts and the majority of the time the decoding completes OK.

Occasionally I receive this exception though:-

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64
 at android.util.Base64.decode(Base64.java:161)
 at android.util.Base64.decode(Base64.java:136)
 at android.util.Base64.decode(Base64.java:118)
```

when decoding the Signature part.

What am I doing wrong when decoding to see this intermittent error?

I then moved onto to using a JWT library to decode the tokens.

first I tried `group: 'com.auth0.android', name: 'jwtdecode', version: '1.1.1'`

the code I tried is

```
 final JWT jwt = new JWT(jwsResult);
```

which consistently fails with the following error

```
com.auth0.android.jwt.DecodeException: The token's payload had an invalid JSON format.
at com.auth0.android.jwt.JWT.parseJson(JWT.java:235)
at com.auth0.android.jwt.JWT.decode(JWT.java:203)
at com.auth0.android.jwt.JWT.<init>(JWT.java:40)
Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 23 path $.
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:899)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:852)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:801)
```

This exception seems to be caused by the Auth0 library being unable to parse headers `4.1.6.  "x5c" (X.509 Certificate Chain) Header` format which is odd as the JWS Spec clearly states the value is represented by a JSON aray:-

```
The "x5c" (X.509 Certificate Chain) Header Parameter contains the
   X.509 public key certificate or certificate chain [RFC5280]
   corresponding to the key used to digitally sign the JWS.  The
   certificate or certificate chain is represented as a JSON array of
   certificate value strings.
```

However If I copy and paste the same jws result string into a pure java project and use `compile 'com.auth0:java-jwt:3.3.0'` and use this code:-

```
String token = "<JWS TOKEN>";
        try {
            final DecodedJWT jwt = JWT.decode(token);
            System.out.println("Header = " + jwt.getHeader());
            System.out.println("Payload = " + jwt.getPayload());
            System.out.println("Signature = " + jwt.getSignature());
                } catch (JWTDecodeException exception){
           throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
```

The Jws Token is decoded successfully.

What am I doing wrong within my Android application that stops the auth0 android jwt library working as desired?

I then tried `'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.0'` library within my Android application.

When I execute this code:-

```
Jwts.parser().parse(jwsResult).getBody();
```

it fails with:-

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A signing key must be specified if the specified JWT is digitally signed.
 at io.jsonwebtoken.lang.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:85)
 at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:331)
```

What signing key do I need to pass to Jwts? The only key I have is my API key held in the Google API Console, is this the key I should employ?

when I pass it as follows:

```
Jwts.parser().setSigningKey<API KEY>.parse(jwsResult).getBody();
```

this fails with:-

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Key bytes can only be specified for HMAC signatures. Please specify a PublicKey or PrivateKey instance.
at io.jsonwebtoken.lang.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:38)
at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:324)
```

What is the correct approach to decode and consume the Jws result received from SafetyNet attest API call?

I discovered a fix for the `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64` issue from this question [Base64: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28584080/base64-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-illegal-character)

simply replace characters in jws token before decoding

```
token.replace('-', '+').replace('_', '/')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I identified this library not only does it do the job it works fine on Android.

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.nimbusds/nimbus-jose-jwt
implementation group: 'com.nimbusds', name: 'nimbus-jose-jwt', version: '5.1'


    try {
        final JWSObject jwsObject = JWSObject.parse(jwsResult);
        System.out.println("header = " + jwsObject.getHeader());
        System.out.println("header = " + jwsObject.getHeader().getX509CertChain());
        System.out.println("payload = " + jwsObject.getPayload().toJSONObject());
        System.out.println("signature = " + jwsObject.getSignature());
        System.out.println("signature = " + jwsObject.getSignature().decodeToString());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Some nice examples are provided:-

https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt/examples