# How To Convert String Into Image - Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, base64

I have the following text which I got from our company's vendor in the form of string. I need to display it as an image using android studio. Please anyone guide. Thanks in advance.

> "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"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert base64 string to image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23979842/convert-base64-string-to-image)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The code provided in theead did not help and display nothing in imageview.  I will appreciate if you share sample code to achieve the same in android,Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved what i needed. Writing the code following if it helps someone, thanks.

```
   Bitmap bm = StringToBitMap(GetString);
   MyPhoto.setImageBitmap(bm);   //MyPhoto is image control.
}

public Bitmap StringToBitMap(String encodedString) {
    try {
        byte[] encodeByte = Base64.decode(encodedString, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you store your image in an `Arraylist` or database in like `R.drawable.bucket` in string form.

Then you can retrieve the image from the string using the following method:

```
Field declaredField;
declaredField = R.drawable.class.getDeclaredField( mTrafficSignalList.get(i)
    .getImagePath()
    .split("\\.")[2]);
MyViewHolder.image_traffic_sign_textview.setImageResource(declaredField.getInt(declaredField));
```