# Convert HTTPResponse to image

Tags: zpl

For one of the implementation, from Java code I am hitting labelary Rest service to convert ZPL formatted code to Image.
I am able to successfully fetch the response. But I am not able to convert the HttpResponse to image file.

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
HttpPost post = new HttpPost "http://api.labelary.com/v1/printers/8dpmm/labels/4x6/0/"); 
byte[] byteArray = Base64.decodeBase64(base64Val.getBytes());
String decodedString = new String(byteArray);
StringEntity requestEntity;
try {
requestEntity = new StringEntity(decodedString);
requestEntity.setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
post.setEntity(requestEntity);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
#Need suggestions to convert BufferReader to Image
}
```

Post referring the suggested answer, code looks like:

`HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
InputStream inStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
String dataString = convertStreamToString(inStream);
byte[] imageBytes = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(dataString);
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes));
File outputfile = new File("myImage.png");
ImageIO.write(image, "png", outputfile);`

Comment: [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50682688/7051704) i think this is the solution you want

Comment: Thanks for the reference.. I used the same code that you had shared. But its failing during the conversion of data string to imagebytes. In debug I can see dataString is not null, still I see "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:". Please advise further.

Comment: I see datastring starting : ‰PNG and then the rest of the string is not readable. Please help.

Comment: @paulrda  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

use this byte to [image converter](https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter). past value in datastring and check whether you get the image.

Comment: The dataString is actually in ASCII format. Code snippet for reference:

Comment: Edited my question to post the latest code snippet. Here the data type conversion to byte array is failing with 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8218. I think post successful conversion to byte array it can be tested with the URL you had suggested. Please help me here.