# Convert encoded base64 image to File object in Android

Tags: java, android, image, blob, android-image

I am trying to use the [AndroidImageSlider](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider) library and populate it with images that I have downloaded as a base64 string.

The library only accepts URLs, R.drawable values, and the File object as parameters.

I am trying to convert the image string to a File object in order to be passed to the library function. I have been able to decode from base_64 and convert to a byte[] so far.

```
String imageData;
byte[] imgBytesData = android.util.Base64.decode(imageData, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: I think it's probably better to create the file using `FileOutputStream` then serve it from a restful URL on the server. Assuming the image data is already in the format you want, just need to write the data to the file. See this SO thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20879639/write-base64-encoded-image-to-file

Comment: But if I was to create a `FileOutputStream`, how am I supposed to access a File object? The library specifically wants the File parameter, is there something more to the `FileOutputStream`?

Comment: just serve from restful url after writing the image to a file. anyhow seems like you got it fixed nice!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll need to save the `File` object to disk for that to work. This method will save the `imageData` string to disk and return the associated `File` object.

```
public static File saveImage(final Context context, final String imageData) {
    final byte[] imgBytesData = android.util.Base64.decode(imageData,
            android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);

    final File file = File.createTempFile("image", null, context.getCacheDir());
    final FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
    try {
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    final BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(
            fileOutputStream);
    try {
        bufferedOutputStream.write(imgBytesData);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
        try {
            bufferedOutputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return file;
}
```

It creates a temporary file in your applications 'cache' directory.  However, you are still responsible for deleting the file once you no longer need it.

Comment: Super thanks bro!, can you please tell me how can we delete these .temp file from app's directory? Thanks in advance