# How to Upload Croppie Photo to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, croppie

I am trying to upload a photo, after being cropped by *croppie* into the GCS.   The gcs write(imageToUpload) method fails because imageToUpload isn't currently a file, but rather a BLOB. Does anyone know a way to make this work? Perhaps, a way in python to convert a BLOB to a file? The image types that can be returned from Croppie are: 1) Canvas, 2) HTML, 3) BLOB and 4)Base64 [Here is the documentation (Ctrl-F "Result")](https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/).  Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `images` pkg in App Engine.

```
from google.appengine.api import images
import urllib2

# if you fetch as image
image        = urllib2.urlopen(the_image_url)   
content_type =  image.headers['Content-Type'] 
image_bytes  = image.read()
image.close()

# if you fetch as bytes
image_bytes  = urllib2.urlopen(the_image_bytes_url) 
content_type = my_image_file.content_type  

filename = '/{}/user/{}_avatar'.format(DEFAULT_GCS_BUCKET_NAME), user_id) # for example

'''
    Create a GCS file with GCS client.
    Make sure you give the GAE app permission to write to your bucket:
    https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlestorage/index#Prerequisites
'''

options={'x-goog-acl': 'public-read', 'Cache-Control': 'private, max-age=0, no-transform'}
with gcs.open(filename, 'w', content_type=content_type, options=options) as f:
    f.write(image_bytes)
    f.close()
```

Comment: This is getting close, but it's still not working 100%.  Do you mind going into a little more detail on the the first line "my_image_file.read()" and of the 4 options I mentioned in my original question, what data format should I be using? Base64?

Comment: Are you given a URL for the image?  Or its bytes?  I have edited the answer with code to fetch from a url

Comment: hmm will it isn't a url, but rather think a `imagedata = _some base64data`, and i can't figure out how to turn imagedata into a image file to store on google cloud storage

Comment: Did you try writing the data, as `image_bytes`, per the last lines of code in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

All you really need to do is just convert the base64 format into a local file so you can upload it.

Please check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20879639/4092401) for details.

Comment: I feel like a complete idiot... I'm using the following code to create my file, but it is breaking at _open_.  Does GAE not support _open_? 
`img_data = b'iVB....
fh = open("imageToSave.png", "wb")
fh.write(img_data.decode('base64'))
fh.close()`

Comment: No, GAE does not support anything that opens local files.

You have to use a FileStream not an actual file in order for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is in PHP but I think you will be able to get the idea and convert it to python.

Croppie Result Method:-

```
logoCropper.croppie('result', {
    type: 'base64',
    size: 'viewport'
})
.then(function (resp) {
   // sends the data to the server using an AJAX call
   // AJAX call data 
   //     data: {
   //       'imagebase64': resp
   //     }
});
```

PHP Endpoint:-

```
$imageName = $some_name.".png";

// extracting the base64 encoded string from the request payload
$imageArray = explode(";", $request->get('imagebase64'));
$imageContents = explode(",", $imageArray[1]);

$imagebase64 = base64_decode($imageContents[1]);

// saving the image to a temp file
$tempPath = sys_get_temp_dir()."/".$imageName;
file_put_contents($tempPath, $imagebase64);

$storageClient = new StorageClient([
        'projectId' => $project_id,
        'keyFilePath' => $credentials_path,
]);

$bucket = $storageClient->bucket($bucketName);
$adapter = new GoogleStorageAdapter($storageClient, $bucket);

$filesystem = new Filesystem($adapter);

// uploading to the google bucket
$stream = fopen($tempPath, 'r+');
$filesystem->writeStream($storage_folder."/".$imageName, $stream, [
        'visibility' => AdapterInterface::VISIBILITY_PRIVATE,
        'metadata' => [
            'contentDisposition' => "attachment; filename={".$imageName."}",
            'ContentType' => "image/png"
        ]
    ]);
```