# Saving Base64 String to file

Tags: java, base64

I am getting a JSON response from webservice call as

[image: ![JSON REsponse from web service call]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRj2v.png)

I have to save this file to my system. I am using the following code:

```
        BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
        byte[] decodedBytes = decoder.decodeBuffer(response);
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedBytes);         
        bis.close();
        File file = new File("C:/image one.jpeg");
        FileOutputStream fop = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fop.write(decodedBytes);
        fop.flush();
        fop.close();
```

The file gets saved but is corrupt and can't be opened. Can anybody shed some light on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `Base64` class from `java.util.Base64`

```
byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64String);
```

Or `Base64` from `org.apache.commons.codec.binary`

```
byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(base64String);
```

And you won't need `ByteArrayInputStream` object

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20879639/write-base64-encoded-image-to-file) for more detailed answer

Comment: Thanks! That worked.. Can you enlighten me as to why did ByteArrayInputStream not work?

Comment: @Ram you have created `ByteArrayInputStream` object but didn't use it anywhere else. The constructor of `ByteArrayInputStream` doesn't change the original array you passed. So I guess the problem was in `BASE64Decoder` class