# Convert base64 to excel file in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, base64

I have a web application from where I am uploading excel file and converting it into base64 and sending it to my rest api as a string, from my rest API i need to read that excel file and then I need to upload that file in my database (MYSQL), I don't want to save the file anywhere on disk, i want to read file in memory.
I searched a lot on internet on how can i convert base64 to excel in java, but unfortunately i am not getting any solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to convert base64 to excel or excel to base64? It's not clear from your question

Comment: Can you add any code you've already tried? Also some explanation of why you do not want to save the file on the disk would be helpful if we are to suggest alternatives.

Comment: Hi @JoelTrauger i got the solution

Comment: Why would you convert to base64? That sounds like an entirely unnecessary conversion step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) is a good library to process excel files, here is a good [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-microsoft-excel) to start with it, basically you have to convert your base base 64 file into an InputStream and from there use one of the WorkBook implementation that Apache POI provides to process the data.

Comment: Thanks David I did the changes and its working

Answer (score 1):

It makes no difference to Java if you have an image or an excel file.
Below is a piece of exemplary code that I think should help you getting started.
It is based on [Write Base64-encoded image to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20879639/write-base64-encoded-image-to-file) and the code provided there for decoding the base 64 encoded file and based on the instructions from https://www.codejava.net/java-se/jdbc/insert-file-data-into-mysql-database-using-jdbc. It should work for many databases as it is using only JDBC, but it is not tested against MySQL.

```
package net.codejava.jdbc;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

class JdbcInsertFileTwo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String base64encoded = "asdf123";

        byte[] excelBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(base64encoded);

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/contactdb";
        String user = "root";
        String password = "secret";

        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password)) {

            PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("insert into table(name, data) " + "values(?,?)");
            statement.setString(1, "My file name.xls");
            statement.setBinaryStream(2, new ByteArrayInputStream(excelBytes), excelBytes.length);

            int row = statement.executeUpdate();
            if (row > 0) {
                System.out.println("The excel file was uploaded.");
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @georg, I have updated my questing, and i dont want to save the file in my hard disk, i want to read it in memory and my database is MYSQL

Comment: I have updated my answer accordingly and provided a code sample for you.

Comment: Thanks it is working

Comment: Glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer if it worked for you, so other users can find it more easily.